# How to write before & after certain substrings in an Open file in python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out how to read a file, find certain substrings, and edit the inputted file to write characters before and after that substring, but i'm stuck. I can only figure out how to write to the end of a file and not in the middle of the file in the middle of a line somewhere!

So for example, say I have a text file:

```
blah blurh blap
```

then I have code:

```
f = open('inputFile.txt', 'r+')
for line in f:                          
    if 'blah' in line:
        f.write('!')
f.close()
```

The way it is written above, the resulting text would say something like:

```
blah blurh blap!
```

but I need a way to figure out for it to say:

```
!blah! blurh blap
```

and I can't figure it out and can't find anything online about it. Any ideas?

Comment: Why is there a ! before blah? Is that intended?

Comment: @timgeb "How to write (a character) before & after certain substrings"?

Comment: @timgeb yes my goal is to be able to surround a substring with another character. Maybe quotes would have been a better example hahaha i want to find a substring and say put quotes around it "like this"

Comment: @cricket_007 oh, I skipped the &, nevermind

Comment: You can't really insert text into a text file.  You are better off completely rewriting the file to a temporary file, and moving the temporary file over the input file once you are done.

Comment: @SvenMarnach ohhh i see thank you! I'll give that a shot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to to this, as mentioned in comments, is to write to a different, temp file then renaming it.

This way is less memory expensive, albeit, it will occupy 2x the space in disk for a moment.

```
import os
with open('inputFile.txt', 'r') as inp, open('outfile.txt', 'w') as out:
    for line in inp:
        out.write(line.replace('blah', '!blah!'))
# Windows doesn't let you overwrite a file, remove it old input first
os.unlink('inputFile.txt')
os.rename('outfile.txt', 'inputFile.txt')
```

Or you can load the file entirely in memory, then re-write it.

```
with open('inputFile.txt', 'r') as inp:
    fixed = inp.read().replace('blah', '!blah!')
with open('inputFile.txt', 'w') as out:
    out.write(fixed)
```

Comment: This fails on windows, because you can't overwrite a file by `os.rename`.

Comment: This is actually Windows being broken, not this code. :)

Answer (score 1):

Open the file, use `replace()` to modify the content and save the result to a string. Then you can write the string to your file.

```
file_name = 'inputFile.txt'

with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
    file_content = f.read().replace('blah', '!blah!')

with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
    f.write(file_content)
```

Comment: Why play with lines?  Why not just `f.read().replace('blah', '!blah!')`?

Comment: @pjvandehaar Thank you, I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Why `file_content = ''`?

Comment: What would you suggest instead?

Comment: Just remove that line.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know to do this sort of thing is to write to a new file and rename it to the old file name at the end.  Something like:

```
def mod_inline(myfilepath):
  tmp = os.tmpnam()
  with open(tmp,'w') as outfile:
     with open(myfilepath, 'r') as infile:
        for line in infile:
          if 'blah' in line:
            outfile.write(line + '!')
          else:
            outfile.write(line)
  os.rename(tmp, myfilepath)
```

Comment: `os.tmpnam` is a bad choice.  Use `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()`.

Comment: You could possibly use mmap and do an in memory edit but it would be more obscure.

Comment: mmap would also probably be limited to 4GB files, depending on the system.

Comment: Not if you did it in chunks.  What is bad about os.tmpnam beyond that it is eventually deprecated?  Anything more?

Comment: @SamanthaAtkins `os.tmpnam` is prone to creating race conditions that result in security issues.  You shouldn't ever use it, there is not reason to.

Answer (score 0):

Input = `sample.txt`

```
blah blub blur
test hello world
```

Code - Read the file, operate on the lines, output to same file

```
filename = 'sample.txt'

# Read the file
with open(filename) as f:
    file_lines = f.readlines()

# Operate on the lines
char = '!'
replace = 'blah'

for i,line in enumerate(file_lines):
    file_lines[i] = line.replace(replace, '{0}{1}{0}'.format(char, replace))

# Overwrite the file with the new content
with open(filename, "w") as f:
    for line in file_lines:
        f.write(line)
```

Output - characters surrounding the string

```
!blah! blub blur
test hello world
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach with the re-module, which allows you to be a little more flexible and define multiple substrings to be surrounded by another string.

Code/Demo:

```
import re

def surround_keysubs(s, ksubs, char):
    regex = '|'.join(ksubs)
    repl_fun = lambda m: '{}{}{}'.format(char, m.group(), char)
    return re.sub(regex, repl_fun, s)

keysubs = {'blah', 'bar'}
char = '!'

with open('testfile') as f:        
    content = surround_keysubs(f.read(), keysubs, char)

with open('testfile', 'w') as out:
    out.write(content)
```

Demo:

```
$ cat testfile 
blah blurh blap
foo bar buzz
blah blurh blap
$ python surround_keysubs.py 
$ cat testfile 
!blah! blurh blap
foo !bar! buzz
!blah! blurh blap
```

Comment: Why one line at a time?  What about `surround_keysubs(f.read(), keysubs, char)`?